# What is the difference between db.collection('collection name).find({}) and mongoosemodel.find({})

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Imagine we have a collection named "People"

What is the difference between these two?

```
db.collection('People').find({})
```

and

```
const People = mongoose.model('people', peopleSchema);
People.find({})
```

I suppose the first one is mongodb syntax and the second one is when we use mongoose. am I right?
I so, can we use them interchangeably?

Comment: Yes, from a query perspective they are the "same".

Comment: You can try the two ways of querying and find for yourself what is the _difference in coding_, and what feels and works better for you. The returned results are likely to be different - not the content - but the way they are available as different type of objects. For example, Mongoose query returns data as an _array_, and the native query returns data as a _cursor_. That means you need to understand what is a cursor and how it works and advantages / disadvantages of using it over an array of data.